# What are the safer and correct alternatives to deprecated `Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStrLn` and why?

Tags: string, haskell, unicode, io, newline

I wonder why `Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStrLn` is deprecated, but
`Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStr` and `Data.ByteString.Lazy.hPutStr` are
not?

```
-- | A synonym for @hPut@, for compatibility
--
hPutStr :: Handle -> ByteString -> IO ()
hPutStr = hPut

-- | Write a ByteString to stdout
putStr :: ByteString -> IO ()
putStr = hPut stdout

-- | Write a ByteString to stdout, appending a newline byte
--
putStrLn :: ByteString -> IO ()
putStrLn ps = hPut stdout ps >> hPut stdout (singleton 0x0a)

{-# DEPRECATED putStrLn
"Use Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.putStrLn instead. (Functions that rely on ASCII encodings belong in Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8)"
  #-}

-- | The interact function takes a function of type @ByteString -> ByteString@
-- as its argument. The entire input from the standard input device is passed
-- to this function as its argument, and the resulting string is output on the
-- standard output device.
```

I thought that that's because the characters stored in the string
won't be output correctly if you do not specify the encoding
explicitly.

But then this should apply to all these functions.

Now I suspect that only the newline character is the reason for
considering this function bad.

Then, I could simply do

```
Data.ByteString.Lazy.putStr myString >> System.IO.putStrLn ""
```

and feel safe about not losing information when doing the output?

The `.Char8` variant feels somehow dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecated `putStrLn` assumes it knows how to encode the `'\n'` character. None of the other functions you listed assume anything about encoding; they just hand off the bytes you pass them. (It is your job to ensure those bytes are correct for the encoding you intend to use.) I agree that the `.Char8` module isn't so hot -- it uses the `latin1` encoding throughout, which doesn't pass the 21st century test. You consider this code:

```
ByteString.putStr myString >> System.IO.putStrLn ""
```

I do not recommend this: it gives you an opportunity to have a mismatch between the encoding you used to construct `myString` and the encoding that `System.IO.putStrLn` is using. Instead, ensure that `myString` has an encoded newline in it at the end.

Comment: In my case, I'm printing encoded JSON (for debugging mostly). And I'm overwhelmed with the compiler warnings about deprecation. Adding a newline to the construction function (`encode :: (ToJSON a) => a -> ByteString`) is not easiliy accessible at all. Now at least I now what the underlying problem, so I won't be afraid of using ByteString everywhere else.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Adding a newline should be as easy as `encode foo <> bar`, where `foo` is your value whose type is an instance of `ToJSON` and `bar` is the encoding of a newline in whatever encoding JSON uses (probably UTF8?).

Comment: I think module `Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8` from [utf8-string](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string) would be a proper place for such a `putStrLn`: it works exactly with the lazy bytestrings, and already [has](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-UTF8.html) functions (which are absent in the basic `Data.ByteString.Lazy`) which deal with newlines, namely: `lines`. (I've already used `Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8` to convert between `String` and `ByteString` in both directions; other methods were Unicode-buggy, even IRC an `IsString` instance...)